# how to change encoding of inserted link in visual studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, parsing

[image]

[image]

Hello everyone, I am writing a simple parser for the exchange rate.
in C #. instead of some of the meanings that he substitutes in Russian "?". I think this is because of UTF-16.
http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp - link to data.

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem with code, people who are volunteering to help need the text of the code. Images of the code are not an acceptable substitute.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: The problem is probably that the font lacks glyphs for the characters you are trying to print. See question about [console & unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ ŤỖŤỖŘŘỖ.

For using webclient to download Russian code (utf16) and output correctly in the console, you could use the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   WebClient wc = new WebClient();
   wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
   byte[] code = wc.DownloadData("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp");
   Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
   Encoding encoding1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
   var convertedBytes = Encoding.Convert(encoding1251, Encoding.UTF8, code);
   string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(convertedBytes);
   Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

The result is shown in the picture:
[image]